# MySQL: compare two columns against single condition

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

Is there any way to compare single condition against two columns (datetime)

sample of current SQL query:

```
select *
from user u
inner join user_info ui on ui.user_id = u.id
where u.create_date > '2015-10-01'
and ui.create_date > '2015-10-01'
```

is there a way to validate "date" by posting it only once in the query?

Comment: yes..if you know they will always be the same

Comment: how?, they will be always the same

Comment: remove either of those conditions

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this.  From where is the query being called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways.  Here is one:

```
select *
from user u inner join
     user_info ui
     on ui.user_id = u.id
where least(u.create_date, ui.create_date) > '2015-10-01';
```